# 2014 holiday/event covariate date data

Tags: data-request, social-media, calendar

I am looking for a dataset of date covariates that could cause a spike in Twitter data. For example, any major news event or holiday such as black friday. Anyone know where this might exist?

Comment: I think in the other direction - use Twitter spikes to recognize major news events.

Comment: Do you have any geographical region of interest? Doing this on an international level is a pretty monumental task.

Comment: Just the united states.